# What is the fire point of sucrose with an average particle diameter of 60 micrometres?

Tags: safety

What is the fire point of sucrose with an average particle diameter of 60 micrometres? I can't seem to find any documentation on this, online.

Comment: "This question was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content." This is an automated process. It would be good if you could add any research you have already done, so that helpful volunteers do not need to do it again.

Comment: http://www.wiley.com/legacy/wileychi/rhodestechnology2e/explosion_hazards.html suggests that fine particle sugar can explode.

Comment: 160 F judging by a MSDS- too explosive for feeble burning to matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the answer in the MSDS of sugar given by the US Department of Labour, after some searching.

In the MSDS found [here](http://www.unitedsugars.com/assets/pdf/quality/MSDS_Powdered.pdf) there is an ignition temperature (which I imagine to be the same as the fire point) of 350 C, with a minimum explosion concentration of 0.045 g/l in air. There also seems to be a possible ignition from a dramatic increase in pressure (mentioned in the MSDS to be 5,000 psi/sec), though no further dangers are expressed.

Comment: I'd say that's explosion point. It burns too feebly to have a fire point- that requires 5 seconds of burning. Its however to find disasters at sugar processing plants.